# Product abstract definition in opencart just like magento?

Tags: magento, opencart

I'm new to open cart and here's one of my concerns:
consider i'm running a shop with opencart and i intend to sell some main products (Mobiles, Tablets, Laptops, ...) online.

Is there a way that i can define an abstract definition of a product type for example named Laptop (with specific attributes, and specific options), therefore when my operator is going to add the new laptop see the list of attributes and fill them and also the same happen in options  tab (all options are defined in the abstract definition and the opreator just customize it for the specific product if needed). So is there a solution for my situation?

ALSO is it possible to define some predefined values for attributes instead of filling them as text? for example think i have an attribute LAPTOP TYPE and i want my operator just select (or multi select)from values {LAPTOP, NETBOOK, ULTRA BOOK}

Comment: For OpenCart questions, ask on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, theres is no one of this features on default opencart, you can extend with plugins like this one that makes what you want, but no select inputs to an atributes, this will implicate many modifications to bd and core files:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=16834&filter_search=attribute